# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "&" when expecting one of the following

Tags: sql, plsql

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "&" when expecting one of the following...

code:

```
Declare
num number;
Begin
num := &num;
if num > 0 then
dbms_output.put_line(‘Hello’);
end if;
end;
/
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this message when I'm not seeing anything wrong.

Comment: Could be a cut/paste error, but you have Microsoft's smart quotes instead of a single quote. You'll want to be sure that is fixed in your actual program.

Comment: Is there anything else being run prior to this block? Has the session had `SET DEFINE OFF` run? This would be the error thrown by Oracle if the IDE weren't doing substitution prior to submitting the block to the PL/SQL engine.

Comment: Are you running this from a SQL\*Plus session? (Or something similar, perhaps SQL Developer or Toad, in the code editing window?) Enter the SQL\*Plus command `show define` (no semi-colon, since it is not a SQL or PL/SQL command); it should respond with `define "&" (hex 26)` or something similar. If it doesn't, you don't have `&` declared as the **define** symbol (marker for substitution variables). Execute `set define &` before you run your anonymous block.

Comment: @mathguy i'm using oracle live.

Comment: I don't know what "oracle live" is; note that the `&` notation for substitution variables is NOT part of SQL, it is specific to SQL\*Plus. It is possible that oracle live does not know of substitution variables, or has a different way to implement them. I would Google "oracle live substitution variables" to see what it brings back.

Comment: I think they might be using https://livesql.oracle.com

Comment: Even in an application that supports substitution variables using `&`, the code above would still be invalid if no value was provided for `&num`.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Live SQL is a tool for trying out SQL and PL/SQL but it doesn't support substitution variable syntax (`&var.`).

Instead, you can create tables, populate them with data, then run SQL or PL/SQL using them, e.g.:

```
create table inputs (num number);

insert into inputs values (10);

Declare
num number;
Begin
select num into num from inputs;
if num > 0 then
dbms_output.put_line('Hello');
end if;
end;
/
```

(p.s. I had to fix the quotes around `'Hello'` for this to work)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle live does not support `&` for get value.
Instead you can initialize the  Variable

```
Declare
num number := 10;
Begin
if num > 0 then
dbms_output.put_line(‘Hello’);
end if;
end;
/
```